# Async iterator in foreach work only one time

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-3.1

I implemented an async iterator that takes data from the database in chunks:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<IEnumerable<Product>> GetProductsByChank(int chankSize)
{
   var collection = Database.GetCollection<Product>(ProductCollectionName);

   var index = 0;

   var isNeedToLoadingItems = true;

   while (isNeedToLoadingItems)
   {
      var query = index == 0
         ? collection.Find(new BsonDocument())
         : collection.Find(Builders<Product>.Filter.Gt(IdFieldName, index));

      var items = await query
         .Limit(chankSize)
         .ToListAsync();

      index += items.Count();
      isNeedToLoadingItems = items.Count() > 0;
      yield return items;             
   }
}
```

And after that i try to use this method in async foreach

```
var b = new List<List<Product>>();
         
await foreach(var x in _productMongoObserver.GetProductsByChank(10))
{
   b.Add((List<Product>)x);
}
```

But foreach only runs once and there are no more calls to the iterator. How can this situation be corrected?

Comment: It will run only 1 time because it reached the end of what it has, lets say you have 100, but say i want 10 it will give you does 10. In `GetProductsByChank`  you can see that, you send 10 and you will `.Limit(chankSize)` AKA 10 only.
So it will return only 10 to the foreach loop

Comment: Your query should also be ordering by `IdFieldName`.